В hibernate получаю ошибку , помогите пожалуйста
Ошибка : Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:660)
at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:13);
Вот код :
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory= new Configuration()
                .addAnnotatedClass(Item.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = null;
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Item item = new Item("Milk",320);
        session.persist(item);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
         sessionFactory.close();
    }
}

Вот класс Item:
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private int price;
    Item(){}
    Item(String title,int Price){
        this.title= title;
        this.price = Price;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("item = [id : %d , title : %s , price : %d]",id,title,price);
    }
}


Вместо sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); нужно вызывать sessionFactory.openSession(); (нужно после каждого открытия закрывать сессию). В чем они отличаются можете посмотреть тут

Тут ошибка конфигурации Hibernate, вот здесь можно взять необходимую конфигурацию.
